# Scrapy : How do i select an element with xpath whose parent element belongs to several classes

Tags: python, css, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract categories from a page online https://www.utsavfashion.in/saree just for training purpose using scrapy. There is a nav-bar with a drop down which has several categories which i want to scrape. All these categories are in between span tags whose parents are li elements that belong to multiple classes. So how would i extract those texts between span tags?

---

level1 = response.xpath('//ul[@class = "level1.nav-submenu.nav-panel"]') . This is one amongst the several other attempts i've made at extracting categories from the drop down. I dont know how to explain myself but basically there's this li tag which has an anchor tag and a span tag under it. The span tag's text is what im looking for.

Comment: Please edit your code to include what you've tried (code). Also, please move your comment into your question as well. You want as many people as possible to see all the information you provide.

Comment: Now you have two comments that need to be moved into your question. Click on the edit button and paste in your comments. Select the code and type control-K to format it properly so it is legible. Thanks.